# An application bundle was not found at the provided path... ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Tags: ios, react-native

I was working through this tutorial, however when I used the react native cli to generate a new project, it would not be able to launch ( with react-native run-ios). I kept getting the above error and I've tried troubleshooting for hours, I think it might be a problem with Xcode as I recently updated it but I'm not sure. Here is the full error message:

> Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/auth.app An
> error was encountered processing the command
> (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2): Failed to install the requested
> application An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
> Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle. Print: Entry,
> ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist Command failed:
> /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier
> build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/auth.app/Info.plist Print:
> Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

If anyone has encountered this problem and fixed it please let me know what works for you! This has put me at a complete standstill and I would greatly appreciate any help. Could this be a versions issue that react native has not caught up with yet? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is something wrong with `react-native init`

Please do not initialize the project with `react-native init ProjectName`

You should append react-native version argument in the end.

For example:

`react-native init ProjectName --version 0.44.2`

Comment: Thank You vary much. You are save my day

Answer (score -1):

If you are using XCode 10 try downgrading to XCode 9.4.1, by downloading and installing this version in official apple portal.

There might be a lot of possibilities of how to fix it, most of them are clearing npm cache, uninstalling node_modules, deleting ios and android folder and rebuilding, so you should try all of them. But downgrading XCode is what helped me after 5 hours at it

Good luck, don't be discouraged with this error, eventually you will find out the solution!