# unable to run react-native project on xcode error Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Tags: ios, objective-c, node.js, react-native, npm

I'm newer to `react-native`.I am using https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html this link to configure react-native for mobile development and trying to run the ios project with command react-native run-ios but i'm unable to run the project.

I have already saw many links about my problem and tried many solutions like
[link1](https://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjPsYuDgsvVAhUJXRoKHZcVDZQQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Ffacebook%2Freact-native%2Fissues%2F7308&usg=AFQjCNGkzXdHc2pfxh6mSxc5-TCDnYjV7A)
[link2](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10401)

[React Native Build Commands Failed: PhaseScriptExecution ... (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35243601/react-native-build-commands-failed-phasescriptexecution-domain-nsposixerro)

[An application bundle was not found at the provided path... ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44572487/an-application-bundle-was-not-found-at-the-provided-path-cfbundleidentifier)

[Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37461703/print-entry-cfbundleidentifier-does-not-exist)

The logs are

```
** BUILD FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/macbook/feed/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/third-party.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Conv.o /Users/macbook/feed/node_modules/react-native/third-party/folly-2016.09.26.00/folly/Conv.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC /Users/macbook/feed/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/third-party.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/StringBase.o /Users/macbook/feed/node_modules/react-native/third-party/folly-2016.09.26.00/folly/StringBase.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(2 failures)

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/feed.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/feed.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
```

I have reinstall node but always problem in  ios react > thirdparty > glog files of ios project.it is also not running in xcode  and give error in glog.logging.h file not found.

```
Mac os version 10.12
Xcode version 8.3.3
react-native version 0.47.1
npm version
{ npm: '5.3.0',
  ares: '1.10.1-DEV',
  cldr: '30.0.3',
  http_parser: '2.7.0',
  icu: '58.2',
  modules: '57',
  node: '8.2.1',
  openssl: '1.0.2l',
  tz: '2016j',
  unicode: '9.0',
  uv: '1.13.1',
  v8: '5.8.283.41',
  zlib: '1.2.11' }
```

Comment: Have you tried solutions in this issue https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7308 ?